# If $f,g$ are analytic in the unit disk, and $|f|^2+|g|^2=1$, then $f,g$ constant.

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to prove that if $f,g$ are analytic in the unit disk, and $|f|^2+|g|^2=1$ for all $z$ in the unit disk, then $f,g$ are constant.

This is an exercise question so it should not be very hard, but I don't know where to start. Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289114/show-that-holomorphic-f-1-f-n-are-constant-if-sum-k-1n-left-f/429226#429226). (Let $f_1=f^2$ and $f_2=g^2$.)

Comment: Seems like this is just an application of Liouville's Theorem

Comment: @mtiano I don't see the connection with Liouville's Theorem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While the comment by Potato points  a way to an answer, this problem is easier (which the answer by Davide Giraudo in the other thread indicates). Namely, for every holomorphic function $f$ we have 
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar z}(f\bar f)
= \frac{\partial}{\partial z}(f\bar f') = f'\bar f' = |f'|^2 \tag1
$$
Apply (1) to $g$ as well, and add the results.

Incidentally, $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar z}$ is $\frac14$ of the Laplacian.

Comment: $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}(f\bar{f}')=f'\bar{f}'+f \frac{\partial ^2\bar{f}}{\partial z\partial \bar{z}}=0$ 
Why does $f \frac{\partial ^2\bar{f}}{\partial z\partial \bar{z}}=0$?

Answer (score 3):

Here's different method. If $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$ and $g(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n z^n$, then Parseval's Identity says

$$
\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} |f(re^{it})|^2 dt = \sum_{n=0}^\infty |a_n|^2r^{2n}
$$

for $0<r<1$, and similarly for $g$. But then

$$
1 = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} (|f(re^{it})|^2+|g(re^{it})|^2) dt = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (|a_n|^2+|b_n|^2) r^{2n},$$

and the only way this can happen is if $a_n=b_n= 0$ for $n \geq 1$.