# Holomorphic functions are constant given that the sum of their moduli is constant.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let $f$ and $g$ be two holomorphic functions on a complex region. If $\left |  f\right |^2 + \left | g \right |^2$ is constant, then show that both of them are constants. I have tried to use Cauchy Riemann eq. and Laplace eq., however I did not manage to solve the problem.

Comment: A more general case is considered here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289114/show-that-holomorphic-f-1-f-n-are-constant-if-sum-k-1n-left-f.

Comment: A answer is given here.:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1410696/prove-that-if-h-f-12-cdots-f-n2-is-constant-then-f-i-is-constant?lq=1