# show that $f$ and $g$ are constant functions in a region D

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

If $f$ and $g$ are analytic functions in a region $D$ and $|f|^2 + |g|^2$ is a constant.

show that $f$ and $g$ are constant functions in a region $D$

*$f$ and $g$ are complex functions*

So far my attempt is a mess.

From writing $|f|^2$ as $f\overline{f}$, $|g|^2$ as $g\overline{g}$ and differentiating it

to using Cauchy-Reimann equations.

None of which is fruitful, hence any help or insights is deeply appreciated.

Comment: More general result here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289114/show-that-holomorphic-f-1-f-n-are-constant-if-sum-k-1n-left-f.