How much of standard complex analysis beyond CIF can be extended to functional calculus?
In holomorphic functional calculus, it seems everything is based on the vector-valued version of the CIF, and results directly about power series and Laurent series can extend there easily.

Q. But can the argument principle, Rouche's theorem, and maximum modulus principle, etc..., also extend there?

It seems the residue theorem should work fine. But inverse function theorem might be difficult, since if $f: D\subset \mathbb{C}\to A$ is holomorphic and injective, where $A$ is a complex unital Banach algebra, I'm not sure what it means for a function $g: f(D)\subset A\to D$ to be "holomorphic".  (It seems range $f(D)$ would be locally $2$-dim in an infinite-dim $A$, if that even makes sense at all)
Thanks in advance.

Are you asking broadly about generalisations for all of those results or are you mainly interested in whether a generalisation for the maximum modulus principle exists?

@DeanMiller Broadly, putting them all in the title is too long. Giving hints/results for any one of them is fine

The Hahn-Banach theorem can very often be used to reduce Banach-valued results to the scalar case because two holomorphic functions $f,g:\Omega\to X$ coincide if the $\mathbb C$-valued functions $\varphi\circ f$ and $\varphi\circ g$ conincide for all $\varphi\in X'$. Moreover, $\varphi$ nicely interchanges with CIF and other standard tools from complex analysis.

@Jochen I know how to prove CIF and Laurent series for holomorphic/meromorphic functions $f: G\to X$, which uses Hahn-Banach. But how to use it to show $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\Gamma \frac{f'}{f}=n\left(f\circ \Gamma\right)$, etc...? I mainly wonder about how to treat $\frac{1}{f}$ when it's not clear whether $f$ takes values in invertible elements, when $X$ is a unital Banach algebra. Do we only consider the situation when $\Gamma$ is such that guarantees invertibility of $f(\Gamma)$?

Might be a tad late, but there is a phenomenon with Banach-valued holomorphic maps in dimension $\geq 2$ where it can happen that maps of constant norm (the equivalent of $\mathbb{C}$-valued maps of constant modulus) aren't constant. In fact, there is a characterisation of the Banach spaces where this can or cannot happen in the answer to [https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2861422/1104384](this post here). As examples, Hilbert spaces don't have this feature, but in $(\mathbb{C}^2, |\cdot|_\infty)$ there's the map $z \in \mathbb{D} \mapsto (z,1)$ which is nonconstant, holomorphic of norm $1$.

I also wouldn't know how to interpret the argument principle for the same reason as you, however one can prove the maximum modulus principle, with the conclusion being that the map will be of constant norm, but nothing more of course due to what I've described above.
