# Question about Maximum Modulus Principle applied to $|f|+|g|$

Tags: complex-analysis, maximum-principle

> Let the functions $f$ and $g$ be holomorphic in $U$ and continuous in $\overline{U}$. Show that $|f(z)| + |g(z)|$ attains its maximum on $\{|z| = 1\}$. Hint: consider the function
>   $h = e^{iα}f + e
> ^{iβ}g$ with suitably chosen constants $α$ and $β$.

Even with the hint I am lost. Of course $|h(z)|$ must attain its maximum when $|z|=1$, and $|h| \le |f|+|g|$, but that doesn't mean that $|f|+|g|$ couldn't attain its maximum inside the unit circle.

ny help?

Comment: Show that for each $z$ in the unit circle, there are $\alpha, \beta$ (depending on $z$ of course) s.t. $|f(z)|+|g(z)|=e^{i\alpha}f(z)+e^{i\beta}g(z)$ and then show that implies the result

Comment: What kind of set is $U$? Was that the unit disk?

Comment: @Lubin I believe so, but the question is phrased with just those informations.

Comment: The hint is not clear to me either as $|f|$ and $|g|$ could achieve maximum at different $z$'s on the boundary. However since $|f|+|g|$ is subharmonic, the maximum principle remains valid.

Comment: Well, if the question is from a text, the notation should appear somewhere earlier there. If the question was posed by an instructor, I would complain, unless that had been standard notation in the course.

Comment: You can use the proof given here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/429226.

Comment: @Pythagoras: The idea is to assume that $|f(z)| + |g(z)|$ assumes its maximum at a point $z_0$ in the interior of the disk, and apply the hint at that point $z_0$. But that is essentially what is written in the answer referenced in my previous comment.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks. Following your idea and the link, I have adapted them into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Martin R. pointed out, the result follows from a similar problem. It boils down to the following statement.

**Proposition**. Assume $f,g$ are holomorphic in a domain $U \subset \mathbb C$, and $|f(z)|+|g(z)|$ achieves maximum at an interior point. Then $f$ and $g$ are constant.

Proof. Suppose $|f(z)|+|g(z)|$ assumes maximum at an interior point $z_0$. Let $\alpha =-\arg f(z_0)$ and $\beta=-\arg g(z_0)$. Define $$h(z)=e^{i\alpha}f(z)+e^{i\beta}g(z),$$ which is holomorphic in $U$. Then $$h(z_0)=|f(z_0)|+|g(z_0)|=|h(z_0)|.$$ Since $$|h(z)|\leq |f(z)|+|g(z)|\leq |f(z_0)|+|g(z_0)|,$$ and $h(z)$ achieves maximum modulus at an interior point, $h(z)$ is a constant, and necessarily $h(z)=h(z_0).$ It follows that $$|h(z_0)|=|h(z)|\leq |f(z)|+|g(z)|\leq |f(z_0)|+|g(z_0)|=|h(z_0)|$$ $$\Rightarrow |f(z)|+|g(z)|~{\rm is~a~constant.}$$ By the result proven [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289114/show-that-holomorphic-f-1-f-n-are-constant-if-sum-k-1n-left-f/429226#429226), both $f$ and $g$ are constant. QED