# Characterisation of $f$ knowing $|f_1(z)|+|f_2(z)|+...+|f_n(z)| = |f(z)|$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\Omega \subset \Bbb C$ an open and connected subset. Let $f,f_i \in H(\Omega)$ for all $i \in  \{1,2,...,n\}$
For all $n \in \Bbb N$, characterise $f$ knowing that,
$$|f_1(z)|+|f_2(z)|+...+|f_n(z)| = |f(z)|$$ for all $z \in \Bbb C$

Comment: Divide  by $f$ and then apply [Show that holomorphic $f_1, . . . , f_n $ are constant if $\sum_{k=1}^n \left| f_k(z) \right|$ is constant.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/289114/42969).