# let $\sum_{k=0}^{n}|f_{k}|^{2}=g$ then if g is constant then $\forall k\in[n].f_{k}$ is constant

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-analysis

let $\sum_{k=0}^{n}|f_{k}|^{2}=g$ and then if g is constant then if $\left\{ f_{k}\right\} _{k=1}^{n}$ is holomorphic then : $\forall k\in[n].f_{k}$  is constant.
My try:
Each of the $f_k$ is has composition to 2 harmonic function $u+iv$ therefore its 2nd derivative is zero.
therefore and because they have the same derivative they must be linear. but linear function accept constant in the entire plane iff they are constant function therefore $f_k must be constant.

Comment: What is the domain of definition of $g$ and $f_k$? If the domain is all the complex plan, each $f_k$ is an entire bounded function, so according to Liouville theorem, each $f_k$ is constant.

Comment: @jvc the same, a general domain G.

Comment: this is not the same question, why has it been closed?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/289114/42969 solves your problem because you can apply it to $f_0^2, \ldots, f_n^2$. I have added another duplicate target which can by applied directly.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $g$ is constant. Let $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ be the usual Hermitian form on $\mathbb C^n$. Take any $z_0$ in the domain.  Let $f(z) = (f_1(z), \ldots, f_n(z))$.  Then $z \mapsto \langle f(z), f(z_0) \rangle$ is holomorphic and by the Schwarz inequality:

$$ \lvert \langle f(z), f(z_0) \rangle \rvert \leq g$$

with equality at $z=z_0$. By the maximum principle $\langle f(z), f(z_0) \rangle = g$ on the connected component of the domain that contains $z_0$.  And again by Schwarz (equality if and only if vectors are dependent) $f(z) = g(z) f(z_0)$ for some holomorphic $g$ with $\lvert g(z)\rvert = 1$. Then $g$ is constant and $f(z) = f(z_0)$.  So $f$ is itself constant.

Comment: interesting can you show it with complex analysis tools?